# How to use regex to find if a text contains specific words?

Tags: regex

I am using a file search tool which can use regex to find files which contain certain text. My regex skills are pretty simple. (I am going to assume the file is treated like a single text with some line breaks)

Let's say I want to find files which contain these 3 words: route,  boy & skill.

How to create two regex's, one to search for those words where each word needs to be a whole word (white space before or after, at beggining or end of line), and another regex where one or more words could be part of another word (like substring function)?

**Update**

I am not interested in regex tutorials and testers. If I need one, I certainly can google for one and find dozens. This is a regex that I simply can't create but which I will use over and over in that tool. Maybe regex doesn't support what I want and a regex expert can tell me that's the case. So no amount of regex tutorials and testers is going to help. I appreciate the links but they are not going to help me here.

Comment: Thttp://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Why the vote to close!?

Comment: Do the files need to contain just any of the 3 words, or all of them? Is there a particular order to these words?

Comment: It needs to contains these words, otherwise I wouldn't use the word I don't want. The words could be in any order and anywhere.

Comment: @Ken I know how to Google. What I want is beyond my regex capabilities.

Comment: And you can test your regex at http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @Tony_Henrich: Then the tutorial should help improve them. :-) A tool like Regex Buddy can help develop, test, and debug them as well. (Not affiliated; just use it myself.)

Comment: What regex parser are you using? This can make a difference. (What programming language or tool if it's from that?) I am not confident that what you want is possible with regex. Regex is a pattern matcher; matching any order words may beyond it's limitations.

Comment: @ken I couldn't. Plain and simple.

Comment: @jpmc26 it's not a programming tool and I don't know what parser it's using. Even though there are differences in parsers, it either would work right away or needs a minimal tweak.

Comment: @Ken You try to help then you put the question on hold as off-topic! Well thanks dude!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following regular expression:

```
(?=.*\broute\b)(?=.*\bboy\b)(?=.*\bskill\b)
```

Comment: This appears to not work if the words are in a different order. Try this sentence: `The boy has skill on his route`

Comment: @jpmc26, `The boy has skill on his route` works for me. (I test it with python re.search).

Comment: Ah, as I said in the comments, the parser can make a difference. Could you add some explanation about how this works?

Comment: I just tested in Python 2.7. I get `None` back from `re.search`: `None is re.search('(?=.*\broute\b)(?=.*\bboy\b)(?=.*\bskill\b)', 'skill boy route')`

Comment: @jpmc26, I think you didn't escape backslash(\\).

Comment: @jpmc26, Escape backslash or use raw string.

Comment: @jpmc26, Without escaping backslash '\b' is interpreted as BEL.

Comment: I created a test text file and kept inserting the 3 words in random places. The tool sometimes found them and sometimes not. I am going to find out why this is happening. You put me in the right track and will try different flavors of you regex. Thanks for taking the time. (and no thanks to the ones who put this on hold so quickly!)

Comment: @Tony_Henrich, I tested all permutation of route, boy, skill .. with space between them. What was the failure case? Give me a example.

Comment: @falsetru The file contains three lines with a linebreak shown as [lb] in each:

well boy[lb]
airplane skill[lb]
superman sun hopeless route ok human[lb]

Comment: Prepending `(?s)` to the regular expression will do the trick. `(?s)` is flag that make `.` to match all including new line.